# Nullable Generics - Implementing SequentialSearchST in C#

Tags: c#, java, generics

For learning purposes, I am implementing certain code from Sedgewick & Wayne's *Algorithms, Fourth Edition*.

Because of language features, a direct translation doesn't seem possible.

For example, I believe the `get` method in their implementation of [SequentialSearchST](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/34hash/SequentialSearchST.java.html) can return null for both value and reference types because Java boxes/unboxes "value objects" (for lack of a better term) like **Integer** automatically.

C#, as far as I can tell, does not have an equivalent built in. It also does not appear to be possible to put an all-purpose [nullable constraint on a generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831157/c-sharp-generic-type-constraint-for-everything-nullable).

At least one other person has tried this, but [their implementation](http://www.rkinteractive.com/blogs/SoftwareDevelopment/post/2011/07/06/Algorithms-In-C-Sequential-Search.aspx) does not allow you to store reference types for `TValue` which prevents you from implementing other *Algorithms* classes like [SeparateChainingHashST](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/34hash/SeparateChainingHashST.java.html).

So, I have decided to throw a runtime error in the static constructor below. Is that about as good as it gets? That is, is there no way to throw a compile time error?

```
public class SequentialSearchSt<TKey, TValue>
{
    private Node first;

    static SequentialSearchSt()
    {
        if (!default(TValue).Equals(null)) throw new InvalidOperationException("TValue must be a nullable or reference type.");
    }

    private class Node
    {
        public TKey key;
        public TValue val;
        public Node next;

        public Node(TKey key, TValue val, Node next)
        {
            this.key = key;
            this.val = val;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public TValue Get(TKey key)
    {
        for (Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
        {
            if (key.Equals(x.key))
            {
                return x.val;
            }
        }
        return default(TValue);
    }

    // more code...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your requirement as it stands effectively means that `TValue` needs to be a reference type. Your method of enforcing this is unnecessary hard and non-standard. [A generic type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) would express this requirement much better and also lead to a compile time error rather than runtime error:

   ```
   public class SequentialSearchSt<TKey, TValue> where TValue : class
   {
        ....
   ```
2. The .NET library team had the same problem you did. Before generics where introduced classes like [`Hashtable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) were provided which would operate on `object` and thus box value types like `int` allowing it to actually return `null` if the key was not present. After generics where introduced this was not an option for classes like `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. The solution to this was to have `Get` throw a `KeyNotFoundException` and to implement a `bool TryGet(TKey key, out TValue value)` method which provides the value through the out parameter and return `true` or `false` depending on whether the key is present or not.
3. You might want to implement an iterator for your list. This will let you use LINQ for a great many constructs usually resulting in more concise code. Something like this:

   ```
   private IEnumerable<Node> AllNodes()
   {
       for (Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
       {
           yield return x;
       }
   }
   ```

   Lets you implement `Get` like this:

   ```
   public TValue Get(TKey key)
   {
       var n = AllNodes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.key == key);
       if (n == null)
           throw KeyNotFoundException();
       return n.val;
   }
   ```
4. Standard C# naming convention is to use `PascalCase` for public `class`/`struct` members. It's a matter of consistency which makes your code easier to read for others.

Comment: Re #1 - the non-standard TValue constraint I have allows for System.Nullable structs like int?, but not int (enforced at compile time for the latter). So, `class` won't work. Re #2 - this effectively answers my question of whether it is possible to throw a compile time error (which is no) - so, I'll mark this as the answer. Between this and @mjolka's answer, it appears that changing the API would make the most sense.

Answer (score 3):

Consider removing the requirement that `default(TValue)` is `null`, and instead of returning `null`, throw a [`KeyNotFoundException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The exception that is thrown when the key specified for accessing an element in a collection does not match any key in the collection.

For convenience, you may also want to provide a [`bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299639(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

If possible, making `SequentialSearchSt<TKey, TValue>` implement `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` will make using the class easier for any .NET developer.

Comment: Re the Interface - I’m hesitant to change their API since so much of it is interdependent. They definitely rely on the null value being returned when a key is not there in other classes. Changes would require careful study and I am still trying to grasp the fundamentals. Re exceptions - I’ve heard it said that throwing exceptions is expensive, so if I were to catch KeyNotFoundException’s when necessary (e.g., during a massive insert into separate-chaining hash table), do you think performance would be significantly reduced?

Comment: @gangreen I understand your concerns, but I really think this is the way to go. The careful study you mention will be good for your understanding of the data structures, and for becoming more familiar with C#. Throwing exceptions is relatively expensive, so providing a non-throwing way of retrieving a value e.g. `TryGetValue` is a good idea.